# how can I return the next for loop item for this method?

Tags: java

I am working on this method where as you can see I have the for loop, but what I want to do is return the next item each time where this method is called (next name). But for the last return statement i am not sure what to put?

I have this so far:

```
public String getChosenInputFileNames() {

setNames();

for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        return String.valueOf(i);
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(i + 1);
    }
}
return null;
```

}

Basically, I want to keep returning the next arrayList Item each time, where I call this method. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is names for a type??

Comment: names is the arraylist, of type String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your method is currently doing is returning `"0"` every time you call it, which is far from your expected behaviour.

What you are trying to do here already exists in the Standard Library. It is called an `Iterator`, specifically `Iterator.next()`.

Here is an example of using `Iterator`.

```
// names contains "Tom", "Dick", "Harry"
Iterator<String> iterator = names.iterator();
System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.next());

/*
Output:
Tom
Dick
Harry
*/
```

See? It is exactly what you want!

Instead of a for loop, you can use a `while` loop with iterators:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

implement/fill a queue using the array list and make a `poll()` every time you call the method... so you dont need to take care of any index in the collection (the queue will do that for you and will return null if you by mistake try to go beyond the size)

example: (please dont use the static if you dont really need it)

```
static Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myQueue.add("2");
    myQueue.add("4");
    myQueue.add("6");
    myQueue.add("8");
    myQueue.add("10");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        System.out.println(getChosenInputFileNames());
    }
}

public static String getChosenInputFileNames() {
    return myQueue.poll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of subsequent return statement you can hold the value of String and then return from last return statement.

```
public String getChosenInputFileNames() {

String name ="";

for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) 
{
    if(your condtion)
    {
       name = names.get(i);
       break;
    }  
}
return name;
}
```